# Display Modal VC from within Category

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview, categories

I have a category branched off from a NSMangedObject Subclass.  It handles the creation and deletion of core data objects.

Inside my creation method, I display a UIAlert to the user asking if they want to configure the new object.  The delegate the responds to the UIAlert is the same category.

I'd like to push the configuration dialog to the screen from within here.  What's the best way of doing this.  My overall application is based on a UITabBarController

does this seem right...

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    AppDelegate *dc = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    //push the Configuration dialog to the screen from here
    NewVC *newVC = [[NewVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"New VC" bundle:nil];

    [dc.tabBarController presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your View Controller the delegate for that `UIAlertView` and present your modal from there. So the `clickedButtonAtIndex` should be moved into the code of your View Controller.

Comment: ah that's interesting. So where do I instantiate that View Controller? Before i display the alert?

Comment: The View Controller is the one in which you are creating your new `NSManagedObject`. It is your visible View Controller.

Comment: oh okay, so what I did not mention was that there is a daemon running in the background that has the ability to add these new NSManagedObject.  There's no specific UI that has the ability to add these objects (it's triggered via bluetooth hardware)

Comment: I see. Then I suppose you have that Tab Bar controller which is always visible. I suggest you subclass it, and make that the action sheet's delegate. In it's subclass you can implement the `clickedButtonAtIndex ` method, and present the modal from there.